# Custom exception handling with function called by list comprehension

Tags: python, exception

I have a function that takes a list or numpy array of integers representing some interval of values which then divides this list into two nearly equal subintervals. This function gets called many times using a list comprehension.

As of now, if the input interval has less than four elements, the function returns None, None. How might I write a custom exception to catch any instance where the interval has less than four elements, alert the user, and not return anything?

```
import numpy as np
from math import floor

def split_interval(hparam_interval, overlap=0.25):
    """
    Divides the original hyperparameter interval into two subintervals with
    a given amount of overlap.

    Keyword arguments:
    hparam_interval -- original hyperparameter interval to be searched over
    overlap -- percent overlap between the resulting subintervals
    """
    hparam_interval.sort()

    seq_len = len(hparam_interval)
    if seq_len < 4:
        return None, None

    halfway = seq_len//2
    seq_overlap = floor(seq_len * overlap)//2

    subseq_low = hparam_interval[:halfway+seq_overlap]
    subseq_hi = hparam_interval[halfway-seq_overlap:]
    return subseq_low, subseq_hi

x = np.arange(0,9).tolist()
y = np.arange(11, 20).tolist()
z = np.arange(2).tolist()

intervals = [x, y, z]
lo_intervals, hi_intervals = zip(*[split_interval(x) for x in intervals])

print(lo_intervals) # ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], None)
```

Ideally, I would replace the first return statement with an exception, and not return anything in the case that any list has less than four elements.

Here is my first go at it:

```
class IntervalDivisionError(Exception):
    pass

def split_interval(hparam_interval, overlap=0.25):
    """
    Divides the original hyperparameter interval into two subintervals with
    a given amount of overlap.

    Keyword arguments:
    hparam_interval -- original hyperparameter interval to be searched over
    overlap -- percent overlap between the resulting subintervals
    """
    hparam_interval.sort()
    seq_len = len(hparam_interval)

    try:
        if seq_len < 4:
            raise IntervalDivisionError("Sequence must be at least length 4!")
    except:
        halfway = seq_len//2
        seq_overlap = floor(seq_len * overlap)//2

        subseq_low = hparam_interval[:halfway+seq_overlap]
        subseq_hi = hparam_interval[halfway-seq_overlap:]
        return subseq_low, subseq_hi

x = np.arange(0,9).tolist()
y = np.arange(11, 20).tolist()
z = np.arange(2).tolist()

intervals2 = [x, y, z]

lo_intervals2, hi_intervals2 = zip(*[split_interval(x) for x in intervals2])

"""
Runs with:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-dd4f490d2b95> in <module>()
     31 intervals2 = [x, y, z]
     32
---> 33 lo_intervals2, hi_intervals2 = zip(*[split_interval(x) for x in 
intervals2])

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
"""
```

I know that I am far from the solution. I am still trying to understand how exceptions work. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just remove `try` and `except`. The way your function is currently written, all raised error are directly excepted in your function and never propagate to the caller.

Comment: That raises the error that I defined, but I would also like to for it to complete the rest of the computation for those lists greater of at least four elements.